# Modes in fstream referring to two different sets ios and fstream for the same thing(in my opinion)

Tags: fstream, file-management

What is the difference between these two lines in file management in C++?

fstream fin("project.csv",fstream::in);
fstream fin("project.csv",ios::in);

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the image for the hierarchy of classes in C++.

[image: Refer to image for hierarchy of classes in c++.]

Actually *ios_base* is the superclass which is inherited by *ios* class, which is inherited by *istream* and *ostream* and both of these are inherited by *iostream* which is later inherited by *fstream*, therefore `ios::in` or `fstream::in` are the same.